# How to make canvas shape circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Hello I want to know how can I make the canvas shape circle in the below code.
The code is about moving a object with keyboard keys. I tried to make the circle out of this box but it just disappeared and i am not really sharp. Can some help me make this canvas circle without affecting code.

sorry but i have to write something more because SO says body has all code... i don't know what to say now (make the canvas circle)(make the canvas circle)(make the canvas circle)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width='800' height='800' border-radius= ></canvas>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

let circle = new Path2D();  // <<< Declaration
circle.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

context.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
context.fill(circle); //   <<< pass circle to context

context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#000066';
context.stroke(circle); 




(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

//event listener
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onKeyDown(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 68: //d
      keyD = true;
      break;
    case 83: //s
      keyS = true;
      break;
    case 65: //a
      keyA = true;
      break;
    case 87: //w
      keyW = true;
      break;
  }
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;

  switch (keyCode) {
    case 68: //d
      keyD = false;
      break;
    case 83: //s
      keyS = false;
      break;
    case 65: //a
      keyA = false;
      break;
    case 87: //w
      keyW = false;
      break;
  }
}

//neccessary variables
var tickX = 10;
var tickY = 10;

var keyW = false;
var keyA = false;
var keyS = false;
var keyD = false;

//main animation function
function drawStuff() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawStuff);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

  c.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
  c.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  c.fillRect(tickX, tickY, 100, 100);

  if (keyD == true) {
    tickX += 1;
  }
  if (keyS == true) {
    tickY += 1;
  }
  if (keyA == true) {
    tickX--;
  }
  if (keyW == true) {
    tickY--;
  }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawStuff);
</script>
```

Comment: @Rajesh - that fixes the example OP gave. The HTML order is likely the issue. Consider reverting the edit?

Comment: uh i don't understand

Comment: Yashu - the script is outside the HTML and the BODY element. Consider moving it before the closing body tag `</body>`?

Comment: You ask about a circle, but the `drawStuff` function draws a square. Did you make a mesh of code you retrieved from somewhere else? I don't really understand what this is supposed to do.

Comment: well yeah its not my code me and my friend are working on a project and I am editing few thinks in it. I didn't made it. can you help i tried to edit it and make it circle but idk i am missing something

Comment: Well, I have to ask: why do you still have code that draws a moving square when you want a moving circle? At the top you have code that draws a circle, but that is not part of the animation cycle, so start by moving that code to where you currently draw a square...

Comment: Also, it seems likely you don't know what requestAnimationFrame does (otherwise I don't get why you drew that circle where you did it). So maybe read some documentation about it. Projects rarely succeed when you just throw in pieces of code from here and there.

Comment: The thing is i have to make it entirely from scratch and i don't want that also it was suppose to be circle idk what happened i am so confused. I tried to fix it but then the whole code is messing. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the `circle` code into the `drawstuff` function as that is where it has to run, and removed the use of `fillRect`.

You can see the result here:

```js
(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

//event listener
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onKeyDown(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 68: //d
      keyD = true;
      break;
    case 83: //s
      keyS = true;
      break;
    case 65: //a
      keyA = true;
      break;
    case 87: //w
      keyW = true;
      break;
  }
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  switch (keyCode) {
    case 68: //d
      keyD = false;
      break;
    case 83: //s
      keyS = false;
      break;
    case 65: //a
      keyA = false;
      break;
    case 87: //w
      keyW = false;
      break;
  }
}

//neccessary variables
var tickX = 10;
var tickY = 10;

var keyW = false;
var keyA = false;
var keyS = false;
var keyD = false;

//main animation function
function drawStuff() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawStuff);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

  c.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  
  let circle = new Path2D();  // <<< Declaration
  circle.arc(100 + tickX, 100 + tickY, 70, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  c.fillStyle = 'purple';
  c.fill(circle); //   <<< pass circle to context

  c.lineWidth = 10;
  c.strokeStyle = '#000066';
  c.stroke(circle); 

  if (keyD == true) {
    tickX += 1;
  }
  if (keyS == true) {
    tickY += 1;
  }
  if (keyA == true) {
    tickX--;
  }
  if (keyW == true) {
    tickY--;
  }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawStuff);
```

```html
Focus this area, then use keys <b>d, s, a, w</b><br />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width='200' height='200' style="border: 1px solid #f4f4f4" ></canvas>
```

Comment: oh sir actually i want to convert the square into circle.  I know the there is function in the code to make it square but when I am trying to edit... i am messing up the whole code